# I draw 7 cards from a standard card deck, what is the probability 5 of them are the same suit?

Tags: probability, statistics, poker

> Apologies for the formatting, I am not familiar with this platform.

I believe I have solved it but I looking for assurance.

Let X be a random variable indicating the number of cards of the same suit (Spade, Diamond, Club, Heart)

I solved the problem by looking at the probability of drawing 5 cards of a *particular* suit and multiplying that number by 4.

> Total number of possibilities when drawing seven cards = nCr(52,7) =
> 133784560 = T
>
> P(X≥5) = P(X=5) + P(X=6) + P(X=7)
>
> P(X≥5) = [nCr(13,5)/T] + [nCr(13,6)/T] + [nCr(13,7)/T]
>
> P(X≥5) = 3.527*10^-5 = probability of getting 5 cards of a particular
> suit

Then I multiplied the answer by 4 to obtain the probability of getting 5 cards of *any* suit

> (3.527*10^-5) * 4 = 1.41*10^-4 = 0.0141%

What do you think?

Comment: Your question lacks precision. *Exactly* $5$ or *at least* $5$ ?

Answer (score 4):

The probability of exactly five spades has $\binom{13}{5}$ in the numerator, yes, for choosing which five spades those were.  It *also* has an additional $\binom{39}{2}$ in the numerator for *choosing which non-spades were also included in the hand*.  Your attempt is missing these additional terms in your numerators.  See [the Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Apart from this, your attempt was correct.

The correct probability is $$4\cdot \dfrac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{2}+\binom{13}{6}\cdot 39 + \binom{13}{7}}{\binom{52}{7}}\approx 0.03056577$$

Comment: Now, If I draw 7 cards from a deck, what is the probability at least 5 of them are the same suit, but this time with replacement (i.e. the same card can be drawn multiple times). Thank you for your response!

Comment: Binomial distribution instead